# How to increment/append radio buttons with JQuery with unique id/name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, increment

What i'm trying to do is to increment/append radio buttons with a simple "confirm/decline" option.
Logically, when we append or increment a radio button, the id and name of a radio button changes.

So what I'm trying to figure out is: whenever we click a button, it will add:

```
<H1>David's Attendance: <span>Confirmed</span></H1>
```

with a confirm and decline radio button, so whenever you choose either options, 
the <span> changes from "Confirmed" to "Declined". That part works.

The problem is when the elements are being generated each time, all the spans change. I want a way to generate radio buttons that only works for that generated H1 "section". The idea is: you click a button to generate an

```
<H1>David's Attendance: <span>Confirmed</span></H1>
```

with a confirm and decline radio button which will change THAT span; Click the button again and it will generate ANOTHER

```
<H1>David's Attendance: <span>Confirmed</span></H1>
```

with a confirm and decline radio button which will change THAT span (instead of all two that have been generated).

I know it's difficult to understand what I'm trying to say, but here is [a visual example of JSFiddle that I got working.](https://jsfiddle.net/u7xgbbwa/)

Thank you for your help everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should note that what you're trying to do, assign dynamic identifiers to elements, is an anti pattern which should be avoided.

To solve the issue in a better way, keep your code DRY by using classes and DOM traversal to find related elements based on the known HTML structure.

In your specific case you can use `closest()` to get the containing `div`, then `find()` to get the `.attendance` element within that, before setting the text based on the chosen radio button. Try this:

```js
$('.add_attr').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var newIndex = $('.attr_entry').length;
  $(".attr_entry:first").clone(true).removeClass('existent').insertAfter(".attr_entry:last").find('input[type="radio"]').prop('name', 'designator[' + newIndex + ']');
});

$('.remove_attr').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $entry = $(this).closest('.attr_entry');
  if ($entry.hasClass('existent')) {
    alert('You can not remove the first attribute entry.');
  } else {
    $entry.remove();
  }
});

$('.radio').change(function() {
  var $attendance = $(this).closest('.attr_entry').find('.attendance');
  $attendance.text(this.value == '1' ? 'Confirmed' : 'Declined');
});
```

```css
h1 {
  color: black;
  font-family: "Courier New", monospace;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="attr_entry existent row">
  <div class="half">
    <h1>David's Attendence: <span class="attendance">Confirmed</span></h1>
    <p>
      <a href="#" class="add_attr"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Another Attribute</a>
      <a href="#" class="remove_attr"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> Remove</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="half">
    <label>
  <input type="radio" name="designator[0]" id="radio1" checked="checked" value="1" class="radio"> Confirm
</label>
    <label>
  <input type="radio" name="designator[0]" value="0" class="radio"> Decline
</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Rory (can't seem to directly reply to a comment), for your solution! Are your familiar with Node JS ? Because i'm trying to append a file in Node JS that would increment the radio buttons each time a form has been submitted.

Comment: Done! Thank you again for your solution, this sure helped me a lot, have a great day!